# Why are these characters considered to be upper case?

Tags: javascript, passwords, special-characters

I am trying to test passwords. I need to do some testing on the string. I am finding that my special characters evaluate to true when I test them with toUpperCase(). I would suspect that they would evaluate to false.

How should I test for special characters?

```
// CREATE ARRAY OF CHARACTERS
CharacterArray = ["1","2","3","a","b","c","D","E","F","/","+",")"];

// TEST CHARACTERS 
function testCharacters() {
    // GET ARRAY LEN
    var CharacterArrayLen = CharacterArray.length;
    // LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
    for (i = 0; i < CharacterArrayLen; i++) {
        // PARSE SINGLE CHARACTER
        var ThisChar = CharacterArray[i];

        if (!isNaN(ThisChar)) {
            alert(ThisChar + ' is numeric!');
        } else {
            if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toUpperCase()) {
                alert(ThisChar + ' is upper case');
            } else if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toLowerCase()) {
                alert(ThisChar + " is lower case");
            }
        }   
    }
}
testCharacters();
```

Comment: Your characters are the same when passed to toUpperCase()- only lower case letters change.

Comment: Wouldn't `+` in upper case just be `+`?

Comment: A better question might include a statement of what you're trying to achieve.  @Sachleen's answer below is probably the approach you want to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't upper or lower case. Both `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` return the same thing for those characters. If you tested for lower case first, you'd find they're all lower case!

You can use some regex to see if the character is in the alphabet.

```
ThisChar.match(/^[a-zA-Z]$/)
```

will return `null` on non-alphabet characters.

If you're just trying to see if each of those characters is in your array, you can use `indexOf`

```
CharacterArray.indexOf('a')
> 3
CharacterArray.indexOf('A')
> -1
```

The second one returns `-1` because `A` is not in the array.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/3/) using regex.

Comment: Testing for `ThisChar.match(/^[a-zA-Z]$/)` tests for basic Latin characters A to Z only; it rejects almost all alphabetic characters, such as ä, é, and α. If you want to regard only A to Z as alphabetic, then you could just as well use the expressions `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` for testing lower and upper case.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela that's what I do in the demo. I am only going off the characters provided in the `CharacterArray`.

Answer (score 2):

The special characters are caseless (neither lower case nor upper case), both by intuition and by the Unicode Standard. But JavaScript has been defined so that for caseless characters, the `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` methods return the character itself.

It is not evident even from the edited question what exactly you wish to test. But if you need to test for a character being an uppercase letter or a lowercase letter, then the suitable *basic* logic in JavaScript is this: if `ThisChar !== ThisChar.toUpperCase()`, then `ThisChar` is a lowercase letter; if ThisChar !== ThisChar.LowerCase()`, then`ThisChar` is an uppercase letter; otherwise, it is caseless—either a special character, or a letter in a writing system that does not make case distinction.

This basic logic fails for some characters, such as the sharp s “ß”, which has no uppercase mapping in Unicode (because the uppercase equivalent is two letters, “SS”, and this must be handled separately). So you need to handle them as special cases if they are relevant.

In other programming languages, you could simply use the General Category property of a character, but JavaScript currently gives no access to it. You could download the relevant file from the Unicode character database, possibly preprocess it to remove unnecessary information, and make your program check the General Category property, but this would be somewhat awkward and would require updates whenever the Unicode standard is changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. If you remove the 'else', so

```
if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toUpperCase()) {
    alert(ThisChar + ' is upper case');
} else if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toLowerCase()) {
    alert(ThisChar + " is lower case");
}
```

becomes

```
if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toUpperCase()) {
    alert(ThisChar + ' is upper case');
} if (ThisChar === ThisChar.toLowerCase()) {
    alert(ThisChar + " is lower case");
}
```

You will see that '/', '+' and '(' are considered both uppercase and lowercase.

This makes sense when you consider functions that determine whether a String is all of a certain case. Would it really make sense to say that "abcde%" is not all lowercase, or that "ABCDE%" is not all uppercase? For both those situations to work, non-letter characters are defined as both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your explanation.  This totally answers the question: "You will see that '/', '+' and '(' are considered both uppercase and lowercase."

Answer (score 1):

Why not use regex?

```
function testCharacters(string) {
    var exp = /^[a-z]+$/ig;
    return exp.test(string);
}
```

Note that with a regular expression you can test the entire string at once, not having to iterate each character.

Comment: I have absolutely no need to test the entire string at once. I am trying to find out exactly what is wrong and let the user know exactly what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. I restated the question and it got jumbled up a bit. Thanks!